# what to choose for primary key in table?

Tags: sql, database

i have a huge table which contains millions of records , assuming my natural key is too large and might change in the future , i want to add a surrogate  primary key  , and will use that surrogate as foreign key in different tables.

- should i leave my natural key also as a primary key ? or it should be just like any other column ?

most of the access for this table is searching by the natural key

- for time performance , should the natural key be removed or defined as alternate key ?
- i dont want to have 2 identical natural keys , how should this be enforced , by using the natural key as primary key also ?
- what does it mean if i use the natural key as primary key and also add another surrogate key and define it also as primary key ?
  i tried searching for examples could really find a good one , links/examples will really help also.

Comment: "assuming my natural key is too large" -- perhaps your assumptions are incorrect so please give more details. "might change in the future" -- stability is a property of a good key; immutability is the ideal but not a prerequisite. But **might** change? [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a simple `INT` datatype primary key and make it `AUTO_INCREMENT` if you are using MySQL, `IDENTITY` if you are using MS SQL Server or `SEQUENCE` if you are using Oracle. The `INT` datatype for primary key is very good if you need performance.

The natural key should be an Indexed column for better search.

Comment: how to to make some column to be indexed ? and how will that enforce that my i dont have my natural key to be duplicated ?

Comment: For example if you are using MySQL you can create a simple index by:

`CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(column_name)`

Comment: I suggest that the index on the natural key should be a unique index, not a repeating index.

Comment: Yes agreed that would be:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name(column_name)`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is to use a database-generated unique key (such as AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL and its siblings in other RDBMS) and create a combined primary key consisting of this and your natural key.

Let me explain why:

A natural key as a secondary unique key has the big disadvantage of creating very bad key localisation: Sequential key values tend to be distributed all around the disk, making very inefficient use of your key cache (no matter how it is implemented, the concept stands). Auto-Increment keys tend to be nearly perfectly localised, i.e. a single page on the disk, which translates into a single disk seek, will very likely contain a bigger part of the keyspace.

By combining a "database-natural" key with an "application-natural" key (in this sequence!!) to a combined primary key, you get best of both worlds. This is especially true, if the natural key consists of some random factor, such as a GUID.

Comment: when i combine them both as a primary key , will that enforce that i dont have duplicate natural key ? , and what do you mean by in this sequence ?

Comment: The opposite - if you combine your surrogate key with your natural key as your primary key, you would be able to have duplicates of the natural key as long as the surrogate keys have different values. Muhammad's approach is much better, as long as you use a *unique* index for the natural key.

Comment: 1.) No, it will not, but nothing stops you from creating your secondary unique key on your natural key 2.) To keep key locality, you need to create PRIMARY KEY(dbkey,naturalkey) and not UNIQUE KEY(naturalkey, dbkey)